# SecRandomCopyBytes and SymmetricKey

Tags: ios, swift, cryptography, apple-cryptokit

Can SymmetricKey be used as substitute for SecRandomCopyBytes?
I found this code snippet in WWDC19 [video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/709/?time=476)

```
var key = Array(repeating: 0, count: 32)
let err = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, keyByteCount, &key)
memset_s(&key, 32, 0, 32)
```

and then use this as substitute:

`let key = SymmetricKey(size: .bits256)`

Documentation for SymetricKey is quite lean. So I am not sure is it safe to use SymmetricKey as CPRNG? If yes, why? Thank you!